# why is protobuf-net deserialized DataType object not displayed with Enum value?

Tags: c#, enums, json.net, protobuf-net

We are using the protobuf-net library in order to decode MQTT messages provided from the Inductive Automation - Ignition software, which is based on sparkplug_b.proto payload.

We have generated c# code with the great online protogen tool (with 'should use Enum' checked). So now we are able to decode the binaries message objects, to human readable JSON for example (see below). But the 'Datatype' is not displayed with the enum value by JSON.net. In the Payload there are available enums, Do we have to do manual changes to the auto generated code in order to fix, this?

```
{
  "Timestamp": 1538568112852,
  "Metrics": [
    {
      "Name": "bdSeq",
      "Timestamp": 1538568112852,
      "Datatype": 4,
      "IsNull": false,
      "LongValue": 0
    }
  ],
  "Seq": 18446744073709551615
}
```

Sincerely,

Comment: _"the 'Datatype' is not displayed with the enum value by JSON.net."_ not quite sure what you mean. With Json.Net If you want enums to be serialized with the names rather than the values, you have to tell the serializer that's what you want: `var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();   settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());` - and then use that serializer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about

```
public ValueOneofCase ValueCase => (ValueOneofCase)__pbn__value.Discriminator;
```

I guess *maybe* your JSON serializer might be skipping it because there isn't a "set" ?